# Best way to handle two very similar classes during data import

Tags: c#, sql-server, architecture, entity-framework-6

**Background:**
I'm building a C# data migration tool to move data from an older application (with SQL Server database) to our new application (also using SQL Server database), but I am going through our Web API rather than direct inserts into the new database to reuse business logic and whatnot. I'm using Entity Framework for reading from the legacy database.

**Issue:**
The older database system, for reasons unknown to me, uses an archive table in addition to the table with the latest version of records. For example, there may be a "person" table and then also an "a_person" table with multiple archived copies of previous records. I am planning to keep these archived records within the same table, just chained together in a Point In Time architecture. So they are essentially identical columns, but because of EF6, these are two different objects which means I'm doubling all my code when I attempt to move values from "person" and "a_person" to the newest data object which will be sent to the API. If it was just the one example, no big deal, but there are about half a dozen tables that have this pattern.

I'm trying to think of the best way to handle this. I initially thought about added interfaces to the generated EF6 classes like semantic sugar to allow passing to a common method, but I still would need to cast that back to the original classes so it doesn't buy me anything.

Next I thought to serialize each of the tables into a json string that I can deserialize into a Dictionary - then have a generic method which would pull my values out. However, I feel like that may be unnecessarily slow.

Most recently I'm thinking about going more back to my original idea with interfaces, but partial classes to the EF6 that implements a common interface and an implementation that can return the different values of the parent EF6 class. So both "parent" and "a_parent" entities would have partial classes which implement an interface and which return all the values for the parent. Again, though, this just feels like a fancier way of duplicating my code of accessing the values.

Serializing and deserializing feels like the only way to truly eliminate the duplicate code. While the length of time the migration takes isn't a critical factor, I'd rather not create the most sluggish solution possible. I guess there's also Reflection. Would Reflection be preferred over the serializing and deserializing?

Comment: Why not get both with EntityFramework and then map them to a single class?

Comment: Entity uses a mapping file that maps the tables/columns of the database to classes in c#.  So you should not have to move data if the mapping is updated to match you latest database architecture.

Comment: Why not unify person and a_person under a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I settled on and was quite happy with, was based on the comment from AlwaysLearning - I unified the two records.